# excel - hide formula for easier input

Tags: excel, input, formula

I have a cell formula that's working mixing both text and an If statement, example:
  `="USER_INPUT" & IF(F2="Asia/Singapore","+08:00","+02:00")`
 output: `USER_INPUT+8:00`
I'm not the one that will use this formula so I'd like to avoid having the user to search for the `"USER_INPUT"` in the whole formula in order to prevent mistakes.
Is it possible for the user just to type whatever he want in the cell wihout having the whole formula behind?
example of cell input I want:

```
="USER_INPUT" & formula
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why the cell containing this formula cannot be in another location which the user does not need to edit?  So I am suggesting that you have a highlighted cell somewhere for user input (say `G2` for the sake of argument), and then in another cell you have the following formula:

```
=G2 & IF(F2="Asia/Singapore","+08:00","+02:00")
```

Your display cell can then refer to the cell containing the above formula.  You could even take things a step further and *lock* the cells which contain the actual formulas, to make sure your users don't accidentally change them.  Follow the link below for information on how to do that.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/214081/xl-how-to-lock-individual-cells-in-a-worksheet

Comment: Then, is it possible to overwrite a cell thank's to a formula? for example: user write "2018-11-10" in D2. in D3 i have my formula: =D2 & IF(F2="Asia/Singapore","+08:00","+02:00"). And in D4 i have something link: write D3 in D2. So i can take the user input the then overwriting it with the return of my formula. I hope it's clear xD

Comment: @Cjdcoy This is exactly what I have in mind.  I think it is a good way to hide the formulas from your end users.

Comment: But there is a problem: if D3 =D2 & IF(F2="Asia/Singapore","+08:00","+02:00")  and then D4 set D2 to the value of D3... then D3 will become the new value of d2 + formula etc... etc..

Comment: But isn't that the whole point?  I'm not sure I see your problem.

Comment: Im saying that's it's doing an infinite loop of editing 1 - > 1 + 2 -> 3 -> 1 + 2 -> 1 + 2 + 2 -> 3 -> 1 + 2 + 2 -> 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 etc... But anyway i searched and you cannot edit a cell from another one. I'm thinking about doing a sheet on which the users write their inputs and having an other sheet containing their input + the formula.

Comment: Why do you need to edit a cell from another one?  You have two types of cells.  First, you have cells into which the user can enter data.  Then you have cells which contain formulas using that input.  Please explain what about this is preventing you from moving forward here.

Comment: "You have two types of cells. First, you have cells into which the user can enter data. Then you have cells which contain formulas using that input". Yea that's what i'm doing with my two sheets. I think that I misunderstood something previously in our discussion xD

Comment: So the pattern I am suggesting is that the presentation/formulas are out of touch to your users.  They can only enter data, but nothing else.